# DSBulk CSV Load Failure to DataStax Astra Cassandra Database, missing file config.json

Tags: cassandra, datastax-astra, dsbulk

I am trying to load a csv into a database in DataStax Astra using the DSBulk tool.

Here is the command I ran minus the sensitive details:

```
dsbulk load -url D:\\App\\data.csv -k data -t data -b D:\\App\\secure-connect-myapp -u username -p password
```

Here is the error I get back:

```
Operation LOAD_20221206-004421-512000 failed: Invalid bundle: missing file config.json.
```

Here is the full log:

```
2022-12-06 00:44:21 INFO  Username and password provided but auth provider not specified, inferring PlainTextAuthProvider
2022-12-06 00:44:21 INFO  A cloud secure connect bundle was provided: ignoring all explicit contact points.
2022-12-06 00:44:21 INFO  A cloud secure connect bundle was provided and selected operation performs writes: changing default consistency level to LOCAL_QUORUM.
2022-12-06 00:44:21 INFO  Operation directory: C:\Program Files\dsbulk-1.10.0\bin\logs\LOAD_20221206-004421-512000
2022-12-06 00:44:21 ERROR Operation LOAD_20221206-004421-512000 failed: Invalid bundle: missing file config.json.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid bundle: missing file config.json
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.cloud.CloudConfigFactory.createCloudConfig(CloudConfigFactory.java:114)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.buildDefaultSessionAsync(SessionBuilder.java:876)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.buildAsync(SessionBuilder.java:817)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:835)
    at com.datastax.oss.dsbulk.workflow.commons.settings.DriverSettings.newSession(DriverSettings.java:560)
    at com.datastax.oss.dsbulk.workflow.load.LoadWorkflow.init(LoadWorkflow.java:145)
    at com.datastax.oss.dsbulk.runner.WorkflowThread.run(WorkflowThread.java:52)
```

The error says that config.json is missing, but it isn't. So I'm stuck. Unless it's looking somewhere other than in the bundle I specified, but the bundle definitely has the config.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error:

```
...
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid bundle: missing file config.json
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.cloud.CloudConfigFactory.createCloudConfig(CloudConfigFactory.java:114)
    ...
```

indicates that [the Java driver bundled with DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkArch.html) is unable to connect to your [Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra) because it couldn't get the configuration details from the [secure connect bundle](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/connect/secure-connect-bundle.html).

Please make sure that the valid secure bundle ZIP is accessible to DSBulk. You need to provide the path to the ZIP file, not just the directory. For example:

```
$ dsbulk ... -b /path/to/secure-connect-db.zip ...
```

Please check the path in your command then try again. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the `cassandra` tag above and click on **Watch tag**.  Thanks!

Comment: That was exactly it, I had unzipped it and pointed to that. Thank you very much.

A note for anyone that incorrectly did the same as me, to resolve this, I at first tried zipping it back up but that did not work. I had to re-download the zipped bundle.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to leverage DataStax Bulk Loader (aka DSBulk, in short), you would need to pass in the secure connect bundle (SCB) correctly. What I mean when I say is that you need either the fully qualified path or the relative path to the SCB file.

The correct command in your case would look like:

```
./dsbulk load -url 'D:\\App\\data.csv' -k data -t data -b 'D:\\App\\secure-connect-myapp.zip' -u username -p password
```

Note that `-b` option takes in the full SCB filename along with `.zip` file extension.

Other Resources:

- [Load data using DSBulk into DataStax Astra DB](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/getting-started/gs-dsbulk.html)
- [`-b` command-line option reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/commonOptions.html#_b_driver_basic_cloud_secure_connect_bundle_secure_connect_database_name_zip)
- **BONUS TIP**: One could easily configure everything within a configuration file and leverage that. See [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkLoadConfigFile.html) for additional details.

Comment: I had unzipped the bundle and pointed to that, that was the problem, I did not realize it needed to remain zipped. Good reminder not to do more than instructed. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're very welcome! And, yes the bundle has to be in a zipped format.